# How to parallelize requests without mecache in PHP?

Tags: php, database, parallel-processing

The page really needs to load fast, but the DB is slow, so we split it into two db calls, one faster and one slower, the first one that is faster runs and we can serve a part of the page that is quite usable by itself.

But then we want the second request to go off, and we know that it will ALWAYS be necessary to do whenever the first request goes off. So now the first part of the page contains a script which fires off http requests and then we make a db call and finally it loads.

But this is a serial opreation, which means the first part of page load needs to both finish its db, return http, render in the browser, run the script, request http then wait for db and finally return us the whole page.

How do you go about solving this in PHP? We dont have memcache and I looked into fifo but we dont have posix_mkfifo function either.

I want to make two db calls on the first request, serve the first request and part of page, let the second db call continue running, when its finished I want to keep it in /tmp/ or a buffer or wherever fast - in memory - and when the script asks for it - perhaps the scripts http req will need to wait for it some more, perhaps its lucky and will get it served from memory already.

But where in memory do you keep it, across requests and php instances? Not in global, not in session, not in memcached. Where? Sockets?? Should I fork and pipe?

EDIT: Thanks, everybody. I went with the two-async-http-requests route.

Comment: What prevents you from firing the second http request together with the first one?

Comment: That wouldnt be the most effecient, it would mean 1 http request to get the scripts which fire 2 requests. Meh. That would be such a typical php "solution". Ugly hack.

Comment: You don't have much room to move here. First, even if you could fork or thread - you still get one incoming request and you can't perform two replies to that, unless you request data 2 times. If you decide to split the fast and slow DB process into two requests - you are now in the domain of JS (because there isn't really another way to deal with that). First request renders the page and 2nd does the magic with the database and can wait until data arrives, IF it arrives. That gives you reliability (you'll know you succeeded or failed). Basically, it's what beniamin suggested in his answer.

Comment: @rapadura I meant exactly what beniamin suggested

Comment: Yeah its a good idea but not a beautiful solution. For example, going with "two async requests from js" but I can only do the 2nd req IF the first succeeds - if a customer exists otherwise it doesnt make sense to do the 2nd query, so the wait has to happen, but I dont want it to make roundtrips between browser-server just for that, hence I wanted to wait for it only on server-side. ms matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use AJAX.
First time send HTML page with 2 javascript AJAX call, one for each sql query, triggered by page load.
Then load page async with those results.

Comment: I kind of like this idea since it moves the problem to the browser away from php. But then the problem is I would have to load three pages, 1st one really slim and two others with slow requests.

Comment: @rapadura I don't think this is an issue. You won't get faster with shared memory or pipes, unless you can reuse data between users or requests. Just watch that session is not locking, if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your problem is to complex to solve it without extra solutions like memcache. Direkt in PHP you can save short data in [SHM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shmop-open.php). But thats not the best solution.

The best solution is to build a better database structure so get a better result and a faster response from your database.

For better performance in your database you can look at MySQL memory tables. But be careful the tables will be cleared after restart. So you can fill the tables with data for caching.

And you can send more then one request at a time with Ajax.

Comment: I cant change or affect the database in any ways, oracle people have that under control and they just wont bother with performance. Ill look into shared memory, I was thinking of fifo in /tmp/ or files in /tmp but that didnt do it, I then need to fork it and I dont have pnctl_fork. Bah.